# Laravel 4 - dependency injection based on configuration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an interface

```
interface RecordsService {
  public function getRecords();
}
```

and two implementations:

```
public class ApiRecordsService implements RecordsService {
  public function getRecords() {
   //get records from api
  }
}


public class DbRecordsService implements RecordsService {
  public function getRecords() {
   //get records from db
  }
}
```

Now, in my controller I do DI like this:

```
class RecordsController {
  private $recordsService;

  public function __construct(RecordsService $recordsService) {
    $this->recordsService= $recordsService;
  }
}
```

And I bind it like this:

```
App::bind('RecordsService', 'ApiRecordsService');
```

Now, my question is, is it possible to implement this more dynamically, based on configuration, something like this:

```
switch( Config::get('config.records_source') ){
   case 'db':
     App::bind('RecordsService', 'DbRecordsService');
     break;
   case 'api':
     App::bind('RecordsService', 'ApiRecordsService');
     break; 
}
```

and more important, is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for that an annonymous function like that:

```
App::bind('RecordsService', function() {
    switch( Config::get('config.records_source') ){
        case 'db':
            return new DbRecordsService;
        case 'api':
            return new ApiRecordsService;
    }
});
```